# Conditional return type for a function without overloads

Tags: typescript

Basically, I want to make Typescript guess the correct return type of a function based on the argument, using generics and narrowing inside the function.

I have two simple interfaces to work with:

```
type A = {
    id:1
}

type B = {
    id:2
}
```

Currently, I am stuck with the approach below -it works btw- however, overloads are also involved. Typescript guesses the return types of `const barA/B` in both cases properly:

```
function foo<T extends A | B>(params:T):T extends A ? string : number
function foo(params:A | B){
    if (params.id === 1) {
        return '100'
    }
    else return 100
}

const barA = foo({id:1})
const barB = foo({id:2})
```

Why is necessary to use overload functions? It feels redundant. Why is it not possible to omit the overload function, and give the return type straight, with only a single function without overloads like this?

```
const foo = <T extends A | B>(params:T):T extends A ? string : number => {
    if (params.id === 1) {
        return '100'
    }
    else return 100
}
```

It gives me Typescipt error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends A ? string : number'.ts(2322)

Comment: This feature is not supported in TypeScript. See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735) for more context. Apart from that, I believe your question is a duplicate

Comment: Your two links helped me understanding what is (not) going on with this topic. Thanks for that!