# How to type a function that converts `bigint` values to `string`

Tags: typescript

Imagine a sanitization function that operates over values, making sure that they are safe to pass to `JSON.stringify`.

```js
type JsonStringifiable<T> = T extends bigint ? string : T;

function getJsonStringifiableValue<T>(value: T): JsonStringifiable<T> {
    if (typeof value === 'bigint') {
        return `${value}`;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This function behaves exactly as I'd expect:

```
> getJsonStringifiableValue(10n)
'10'
> getJsonStringifiableValue(10)
10
> getJsonStringifiableValue('10')
'10'
```

Despite that, it does not typecheck.

```js
if (typeof value === 'bigint') {
    return `${value}`; // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'JsonStringifiable<T>'.
} else {
    return value; // ERROR: Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'JsonStringifiable<T>'.
}
```

Why?

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYGVgCcCWSDmmBmmAhgEYA2EAPACoB8UAvFNVBAB7ARIAmcUJmPEmBQA-FDgZsOKAC4ozANwAoZfgCuSAMbBMyKDgjB4yNFlwFi5CADUiZdVToAKAG73H86gEp5J1FIWhKQUNPQA3soKCgRQzqCQCPhQ7g7QDBlQAOQCQsBZ3lCR0SVQ6Ebq6EhQAAYAJOGpjgC+NSolzaxkcNDFpQrlwJXVTRDt0c3KzUA).

Comment: You should be using overloads: https://tsplay.dev/N55X0N

Comment: That would work, @vr., but why doesn't it work as written? In particular, _using_ `getJsonStringifiableValue` returns exactly the types it should given various inputs (ie. returns a `string` if passed a `bigint` and flows the type through otherwise). It's the implementation that's not passing typechecking, and I can't see why.

Comment: For more complex functions, it quickly becomes impossible to determine whether or not the implementation actually matches the return type. It's simply just not designed to do this.

Comment: What is ‘it’ in this case? Typescript? Typescript conditional types are designed to do exactly this, as you can see by the return type of the function behaving correctly, @vr.. The thing I don't understand is why the very straightforward implementation isn't sufficient to refine `value` to the point where Typescript is like ‘oh yeah, this is for sure a `bigint` and the return type is `number` so this satisfies `JsonStringifiable<T>`.’

Comment: I can't say I completely understand why, but the best intuition I have is that it's because your annotated return type is some type that itself is conditional on generic parameterization. But your code is simply conditionally returning either a `string` or `T` type, depending on the branch, which is what describes the `string | T` type. I think that's the subtle difference. To get the behavior you most likely want, simply cast each return using `as JsonStringifiable<T>`.

Comment: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYGVgCcCWSDmmBmmAhgEYA2EAPACoB8UAvFNVBAB7ARIAmcUJmPEmBQA-FDgZsOKAC4ozANwAoZfgCuSAMbBMyKDgjB4yNFlwFi5CADUiZdVToAKAG73H86gEp5J1FIWhKQUNPQA3soKCgRQzqCQCPhQ7g7QDBlQAOQCQsBZ3lCR0SVQ6Ebq6EhQAAYAJOGpjgC+NVBEfP5m0pYhTrQqJc2sZHDQxaUK5cCV1U3QHbCIAeZ4wdZhg9HNyjvKWsiS7YwGRl2Ba1YUdmnOAEwADA-eKgdIRyQnhsbL3UFXtg8EGcACIABYQMhkBAgl77Q4iLRfM6-C69aw3RzOAAsSBeQA) for my suggestion above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional types are written correctly and work just fine when not used in a function's return type. Demonstrating this ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=5&ssc=28&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYGVgCcCWSDmmBmmAhgEYA2EAPACoB8UAvFNVBAB7ARIAmcUJmPEmBQA-FDgZsOKAC4ozANwAoZaEhQAYkQDGVagDUiZAK4R6TeMjRZcBYuX1HT55TuSSJGedr2UBQsAWUDbSABQAQoIAksJhAKwAlIluHiJIJgC2PrpUGZkkEOjBAIyq%20CZIOsCYyFA4EMBWqFJ2hKQUzmY0tGEAbsZm8tSJ8s2hbQ4UPVAA3soKCgRQYeoQCPhQAy6MDEwA5AHYwPuJcwuLl%20iNJuhIUAAGACSz22YAvg8ql%20%20sZHDQeaXK43O5bQYQb6Ld7Kd5AA)):

```js
type JsonStringifiable<T> = T extends bigint ? string :  T;

type Face<TValue> = JsonStringifiable<TValue>
const str: Face<bigint> = String(BigInt(5))
const num: Face<number> = 1
```

The only thing that doesn't work in your typing is using conditional types in a function's return type position. TypeScript just does not support this yet. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72159080/conditional-return-type-for-a-function-without-overloads#comment127495698_72159080) documents this with some examples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735).

My understanding is that support for this feature is being tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), although the problem description is slightly different.

While @vr's comment happens to be correct with no explanation of why, I do believe a function overload (which offers very little type safety) is the best you can currently do given this limitation in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional types are types, too. This function doesn't have two different return types depending on the input value, or its type - it has one return type, and that is `T extends bigint ? string : T`.

So then the question is whether all return statements in the function return something that satisfies this type. Unfortunately, since `T` is a type parameter which could be realised as any type, Typescript doesn't have much logic for testing whether a given expression has the type `T extends bigint ? string : T`. What it does see is that the first return statement returns an expression of type `string`, and the second returns an expression of type `T`, but it doesn't know that either of these types is assignable to `T extends bigint ? string : T`.

Now, there is also type narrowing going on because of your `if` condition; in particular, in the positive branch, the variable `value` has its type narrowed to `T & bigint`, as can be seen in the hover tooltip. Unfortunately that is not enough for your code to typecheck; the type of the variable `value` is narrowed, but the `if` statement's condition does not narrow the type variable `T` itself. It is therefore not possible for the compiler to determine that `string` is assignable to `T extends bigint ? string : T`.

In principle a smarter type-checker could narrow `T` itself, but this would be tricky to do correctly. The condition `typeof value === 'bigint'` does not imply that `T = bigint`, it only implies that `T` is some type which has a non-empty intersection with `bigint`. For example, `T` could be `"foo" | 2n`, a union of two literals, one of which is a bigint literal. So a smarter version of Typescript could theoretically narrow `T` from "an unknown type parameter" to "an unknown type parameter whose intersection with `bigint` is not empty", but that's complicated, and the real Typescript compiler has no way to represent such a type, let alone reason about it.

So generally speaking, when a function's return type is a conditional type that involves a generic type parameter, you're going to have to use `as` to assert to the compiler that your code is correct, because the compiler isn't advanced enough to check it. Alternatively, you should rewrite your code to avoid conditional types. (Note that things like `Exclude` are defined as conditional types, too.) Here's an example which uses union types instead:

```
function getJsonStringifiableValue<T>(value: T | bigint): T | string {
    if (typeof value === 'bigint') {
        return `${value}`;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This typechecks just fine, though whether or not it works for your use-case I am not sure.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQFIGcEGUoBOMYyMwMAhgEYA2qAahTSKgDwAqAfABQBuTLAFyJ2iAD6IqMUmCgBKYaIlZCxZIgDeAKES7EZRNygBPAA6o4wRP2apEAXkeIA5FJlRnczTr2+C6EAIkAAMAEg0bFgBfYIBuH10oxFQaLDttXz8AoOsBVHjfKK0ooA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is not, unfortunately. This is the sort of performance I expect from that function: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13243/225476371-830e52a8-5d5a-4a05-a497-4d596f99d29c.png

Comment: @steveluscher Well, the code you wrote won't work for that input value, because it's an array, not a bigint.

Comment: Oh, that screenshot was not related to the code in this question. The code in this question is a _reduced test case_ of the problem. The code in the screenshot is my desired endgame.